# php увеличить значения переменной

Tags: php

Есть массив в таком формате:

```
$arr = ['0000','0001','0002', '0003']; //и тд...
```

Мне нужно взять последнее значении массива и увеличить его на +1.Сделать что то в этом роде.

```
$last = $arr[3]++;
```

На выходе получить 0004. Только как можно такое сделать немогу понять, конвертировать интерпретатор будет в 4. Данные массива будут увеличиваться всегда. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `++` имеет две формы - префиксный инкремент - `++i` и постфиксный инкремент - `i++`. Префиксный возвращает увеличенное значение, постфиксный - то, которое было до увеличения. Вам нужен префиксный вариант:

```
$arr = ['0000','0001','0002', '0003'];
$last = ++$arr[3]; 
echo $last;        // 4
echo $arr[3];      // 4
```

если вопрос про дописывание 000 и конвертацию в строку, то решение:

```
$arr[3] = str_pad($arr[3], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $arr[3];      // 0004
```

Comment: ну это не столь важно в моей проблеме.

Comment: @depredator а в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: Как увеличить строку 0003 что бы получить 0004 ?

Comment: @depredator добить нулями после увеличения. добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Если формат всегда одинаковый

```
$number = $arr[count($arr) - 1] + 1;
$incremented = str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Но вообще вы путаете данные и представление. Данные у вас всегда должны оставаться числами, переходить в вышеуказанный формат они должны только при выводе.

Comment: Данные берутся из файла. Берется последнее число 0004, увеличивается на 1, и снова записывается в файл.

Comment: @depredator Вероятнее всего, там должно быть просто 4, да и не в файле, а в БД.

Answer (score 1):

Конвертировать после увеличения из 4 обратно в строку нужного формата?

```
$strVal = (string)$intVal;
for ($i=strlen ($strVal); i<=4; i++) {
'0'.$strVal;}
```

а что после 9999? Непонятно, какой формат у вас